# Drush command from contrib module not recognized

Tags: drush

I have installed a new module called [S3fs](https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs) using Composer. When I try to execute `/root/.composer/vendor/bin/drush drush_s3fs_copy_local`, it shows the following error.

> Command "drush_s3fs_copy_local" is not defined

I found out that I could not run any command from third-party modules I installed and enabled.

Please help me.

Comment: try to run `drush cc drush` before.

Comment: hi my drush version is 9.5.2 and drupal is 8.6.4. Module is already enabled

Comment: hi any advice on this please

Comment: how did you install the module, with drush or composer ?

Answer (score 0):

`drush_s3fs_copy_local` is the name of the PHP callback function for the command; the command itself is named `s3fs-copy-local`, with an alias of `s3fs-cl`.

So:

```
drush s3fs-cl
```

Is what you're looking for.

Comment: yeah i tried this it didn't work.s3fs module is enabled. my drush version is 9.5.2 and drupal is 8.6.4.